# Merging two associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have been trying to merge two associative arrays all day. But I don't know whether it is possible or not in PHP.

**first array**

```
  'images' => 
      0 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/iphone.png'
      1 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/1425328_405486846250283_806381377_o.jpg'
      2 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bbg.jpg'
      3 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/gmail_bg.JPG'
```

**second array**

```
'images' => 
      0 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/Capture.JPG'
      1 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bg.jpg'
      2 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/abc.JPG'
      3 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bg_dark.png'
      4 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bktile.png'
```

And they should be merged together like this.

**merged array**

```
  'images' => 
      0 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/iphone.png'
      1 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/1425328_405486846250283_806381377_o.jpg'
      2 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bbg.jpg'
      3 => 
          'image_first' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/gmail_bg.JPG'
      4 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/Capture.JPG'
      5 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bg.jpg'
      6 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/abc.JPG'
      7 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bg_dark.png'
      8 => 
          'image_second' => string 'http://10.0.2.2/captcha-2/bktile.png'
```

How to do it?

Comment: [array_merge](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) - Did you even consult the docs?

Comment: Do you want other result than array_merge? If so you should give output you expect not only what was your result

Comment: Seriously? https://www.google.com/search?q=php+merge+two+array

Comment: this is not a simple array mergin, this is an array inside another array

Comment: see the whole array is inside another array images

Comment: `array_merge($arr1['images'], $arr2['images'])`

Comment: array_merge() will replace existing keys. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

`array_merge()` will do the trick.
See https://www.php.net/array_merge.

Comment: -1 because: from the docs 'If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. 'see @Fydo's answer

Comment: @pc-shooter Literally the next sentence in the documentation: "If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

Comment: @pc-shooter -1 your comment, because when the array has numeric keys, they are not replaced. See @ php documentation's answer.

Comment: @theHacker ooops!! sry for that!! I can't vote up again, until you edit your answer... But I will, as soon as I can!!

Comment: @pc-shooter did edit, hope that helps :-)

Comment: @theHacker +1 sry again!